# CakePHP handling checkbox in view

Tags: cakephp

I have a Table column named `active` which may have a value 1 or 0

in my `add.ctp` I am creating a checkbox using

```
<?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('active'); ?>
```

and similarly in my `edit.ctp` template

but regardless of if the checkbox is checked or unchecked the value saved in Database is always 1 and i also don't know in the `active=1` how to set it to `checked`

Comment: As Cowls says, use a boolean value in your database and it will automatically work fine if your controller is action is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the database column is a BOOLEAN type. You should create the checkbox like this instead:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('active'); ?>
```

It should automatically output it as a checkbox..

If it doesn't, try clearing the model cache in `tmp/cache/models` and trying again